# PySpark SQLContext.createDataFrame producing nulls when declared and actual field types don't match

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In PySpark (v1.6.2) when converting an RDD to a DataFrame with a specified schema, fields who's value type doesn't match the one declared in the schema get converted to `null`.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("foo", DoubleType(), nullable=False)
])

rdd = sc.parallelize([{"foo": 1}])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=schema)

print df.show()

+----+
| foo|
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

Is this a PySpark bug or just very surprising but intended behaviour? I would either expect a `TypeError` to be raised or for the `int` to be converted to `float` compatible with `DoubleType`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This an intended behavior. In particular see the comments to the [corresponding part of the source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/86ca8fefc8a147b31952b8a00e58e46d93bb8bc4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/python/EvaluatePython.scala#L158-L160):

```scala
// all other unexpected type should be null, or we will have runtime exception
// TODO(davies): we could improve this by try to cast the object to expected type
case (c, _) => null
```